# Find all available OLE containers

Tags: windows, com, registry, activex, ole

Found out that entries at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\ that contain "verb" subkey represent OLE containers.

Like

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{GUID_HERE}\verb\
```

Question:

Is this necessary and sufficient condition to distinguish COM and OLEs (i.e is this trait necessary for all OLE's or not)?

Answer (score 2):

OLE containers do not need to have any subkeys.  In fact, they do not need to have any registry entries at all.  All they have to do is implement a few predefined interfaces.

If you are talking about OLE servers, they usually implement some verbs that can be called through IOleObject.DoVerb().  They also usually implement MiscStatus.